# Несколько вопросов про Алгоритм Diffie-Hellman'a

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, protocol

Решая CTF, в котором было предоставлено задание,в котором было сказано расшифровать дамп трафика TLS, я познакомился с алгоритмом Диффи-Хелмана.

В классике шифр работает как показано на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь сами вопросы:

1. Если число `p` было не простое, это делает его уязвимым к ??? Не очень понятно, почему если число `p` - простое, оно менее уязвимо.
2. Где генерируется `p & g` - на сервере, или на клиенте и если это согласовывается, то где?
3. Может ли в реальных условиях встретится такое, что `p` и (или) `g` числа не простые?

Answer (score 0):

**Дисклеймер:** Я не криптоаналитик и вообще с трудом ориентируюсь в теории чисел.
Здесь и далее подразумеваются обозначения из [изложения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) в вики.

---

> В данном примере число "p" было не простым, что делает его уязвимым к ??? Не очень понятно, почему если число "p" - простое, оно менее уязвимо.

Как написано во всех букварях, надёжность протокола Диффи—Хеллмана основана на сложности дискретного логорифмирования, т.е. нахождения такого *а*, что *A ≡ g<sup>a</sup> (mod p)*. Если *p* будет составным, то это собственно сильно упростит дело. Если кратко, то нужно найти все a<sub>i</sub> для всех делителей p<sub>i</sub>, таких что *A ≡ g<sup>a<sub>i</sub></sup> (mod p<sub>i</sub>)* с помощью «тяжёлых» методов, например, с помощью ро-метода Полларда, а затем с помощью китайской теоремы об остатках и малой теоремы Ферма вычислить *a*. Нахождение общего секрета далее — тривиальная задача. Хорошее подробное описание этого алгоритма есть на [code.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67093/diffie-hellman-private-key-recover-with-non-prime-modulus?newreg=6f221d01473743b1b5693a4bfeb37464).

> Где генерируется "p" & "g" - на сервере, или на клиенте и если это согласовывается, то где?

Генерация `p` относительно тяжёлый и ответственный процесс: может занимать от нескольких секунд до нескольких часов и в случае неудачного значения криптостойкость алгоритма сильно страдает. В качестве `g` выбирается обычно очень небольшое число, например `2`. Так что эти значения генерируются «заранее». В частности не редко используются заранее вычисленные константы, например, для того же TLS 1.3 они есть прямо в [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7919#appendix-A) протокола. Для других протоколов, в частности более старых версий TLS, они обычно хранятся на сервере.

> Может ли в реальных условиях встретится такое, что "p" и (или) "g" числа не прсотые?

Может. Иногда это может произойти по ошибке т.к. проверка больших чисел на простоту — процесс стохастический. Но иногда это вызывает [подозрения в бекдорах](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32415/how-does-a-non-prime-modulus-for-diffie-hellman-allow-for-a-backdoor). Простота *g*, вообще говоря, не имеет значения. Важно, чтобы оно порождало достаточно большую подгруппу в Z<sub>p</sub>.

---

Также для общего обзора см. *Брюс Шнайер — «Прикладная криптография»*: главы 11 и 22.1.